# Replacement of single space with sed without touching multiple spaces

Tags: shell, sed

Replacement of single space using `sed` without touching sequences of several spaces.

I have file that looks like this:

```
Host/Domain Summary: Message Delivery
 sent cnt  bytes   defers   avg dly max dly host/domain

 -------- -------  -------  ------- ------- -----------
    937     3293k       0    18.6 s    6.9 m  theory.tifr.res.in

    462     3740k       0     7.3 s    9.5 m  ncra.tifr.res.in

    286     1053k       4    20.4 s    1.3 h  gmail.com
```

Question:

I want to replace only single space with comma or without space but without touching other spaces. I have tried it with `sed` but it directly takes all space and replaces them with a comma.

Example: 18.6 s and 6.9 m having single space so that can only replace by value which we give in `sed` but others cannot.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a funny thing to be doing, but this should do what you say you want to do:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/\1,\2/g'
```

Replace a non-blank followed by a blank followed by another non-blank with the first non-blank, a comma, and the second non-blank.  Repeat for each single blank in the line.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler@ thanks alot I dont know how I forgot this....I made small change as per my req. removed "," and keep this as it is. 

sed 's/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/\1\2/g'

Thanks a lot

Comment: `sed -e 's/\b \b/,/g'` should do just fine `\b` is word boundary

Comment: A couple of notes: (1) Some versions of `sed` support the `\b` notation; others do not (GNU `sed` does, and is very widely used). (2) Replacing the single space with nothing makes more sense than the comma, and if you want to ensure that you're combining a number (digit) with its units (rather than running two words together), you can adjust the character classes (`s/\([0-9\.]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)/\1/2/` etc).